# Constraints on Nested Tags in Launch Files

Tags: ros, roslaunch, include, rosparam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What kinds of tag nesting are allowed in ROS launch files?

For instance, I know I can have global params within the `<launch>` tag as well as node params within a specific `<node>` tag.

But can other things be nested inside of the `<node>` tag, such as `<rosparam>`, `<include>`, other `<node>` tags?

Example 1:

```
<node>
    <rosparam ... some-file.yml />
</node>
```

Example 2:

```
<node>
    <include ... />
</node>
```

Example 3:

```
<node>
    <node ... >
        ...
    </node>
</node>
```

It seems like example 3 would be illegal, but I am unsure about example 1 and 2. Any help is appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33288/constraints-on-nested-tags-in-launch-files/) by [jbranchaud](https://answers.ros.org/users/2316/jbranchaud/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2012-05-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [roslaunch/XML](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML) wiki page explicitly lays out what types of nesting are allowed. If you go down to the tag reference, each tag has an Elements section which says what elements are allowed inside that particular tag.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3